# How to get url from website elements and open it in another window

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm trying to open web url what is hidden in elements, but if i click on button what in on web page, it shows up in the elements.
So want to use javascript, when i click on button, then javascript find that url and open it in another window.
I want to use tampermonkey, the userscript manager to run that script.
Iam new to coding, except wrong code.

I already tried some commands like this: `document.getElementById("vjs_tech")`
it shows up like `<video *there are some random*` and `src="https://and some random words"></video>`
and i tried use method `window.open("src")`.

```
document.getElementById("vjs_tech");
window.open("src");
```

I excepted that will open the link from src but it only opened same window again.

Comment: Well you would need to read the URL from the element. No clue what the element is so hard to help you.

Comment: Can you edit this question to fix some of the grammar, clarify what you're trying to do, and include more complete/explicit code examples? I suggest [fenced code blocks](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks#fenced-code-blocks).

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the value of src attribute from the element.

```
var videoURL = document.getElementById('vjs_tech').src;
window.open(videoURL);
```